# Angular $http error callback not executing

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http

I have nested http calls in my angular application.

```
$scope.saveAsPaused = function() {

                var cmsResponse = saveAtCMS();
                cmsResponse.then(function(data){

                        saveAtRe(data).then(function(data){

                                successSave(data);
                        }, function(data, isOffDel){

                                delOnFailRE(data);
                        });
                });
      }

var saveAtRe = function(data) {
            return $http.post('/pause', data);
        }
```

Backend Code in JAVA

```
    @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/pause")
    public Response createInPauseState(CampaignConfigurationBeans camp) {

         return Response.status(502).entity("false").build();

    }
```

In **saveAtRe** function, I am returning a status code of 502 from backend but still, my application is calling successSave function.

Can anybody explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can u share your backend code too, that will help to understand.

Comment: can u try using Response.Status.BAD_GATEWAY instead of 502. I am not very sure it will work, but in doc http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Status.html#BAD_GATEWAY , it says 502 Bad Gateway and not just 502.

Answer (score 0):

From [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success
>   status and will result in the success callback being called

502 status code expected to trigger error callback, your code looks ok. Could you double check returned status in success callback, e.g.

```
 saveAtRe(data).then(function(data){
                            console.log(data.status);
                    }, function(data, isOffDel){
                            delOnFailRE(data);
                    });
```

If received status is 502, then it is not general behavior and I would check if additional Angular's http interceptors applied in your code.

Comment: Yes, status is coming as 502.I have verified that.

Comment: [Angular's code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js) is quite straightforward there. `function isSuccess(status) {
  return 200 <= status && status < 300;
}` There must be some application's custom logic applied.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to you

```
$scope.saveAsPaused = function() {
                var cmsResponse = saveAtCMS();
                cmsResponse.then(function(data){
                        saveAtRe(data).then(function(data){
                                successSave(data);
                        }, function(data, isOffDel){

                                delOnFailRE(data);
                        });
                });
           }
        var saveAtRe = function(data) {
          var q=$q.defer();
          $http.post('/pause', data).then(function(data)
            {
               q.resolve(data);
            },function(error){
               q.reject(error);
            })
          return q.promise;;
        }
```

Comment: That's an antipattern, `$http.post(...)` itself returns promise

Comment: Wrapping promise into other one, what is the difference?

Comment: @gitaram, yes previously I was using this pattern only and it was working fine.But I didnot understand why its not working the way I mentioned in my question.